# Detect if page is loaded inside WKWebView in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, mobile-safari, wkwebview

How can I reliably detect using javascript that a page is loaded inside a WKWebView? I'd like to be able to detect these scenarios:

- iOS & WKWebView
- iOS & Safari
- not iOS

There is a similar question about UIWebView [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460205/detect-ipad-iphone-webview-via-javascript). But it's quite old and I'm not sure if same still applies to WKWebView.

Comment: Why? It may be we can give you a better approach to your underlying goal.

Comment: You aren't sure if the method described in the other question works.  Then try it!

Comment: Certain features of the page will work differently if loaded inside WKWebView. For example it will use native classes to optimize file uploading.

Comment: I try all this solutions, but not worked for me, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41108335/1290278)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Update:** This no longer works, see the higher-rated answers above instead!

You can check for the existence of `window.webkit.messageHandlers` which WKWebKit uses to receive messages from JavaScript.  If it exists, you're inside a `WKWebView`.

That combined with a simple user agent check should do the trick:

```
var iOS = (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g) ? true : false);
var isWKWebView = false;
if (window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers) {
    isWKWebView = true;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. Together with iOS check it should provide reliable results.

Comment: The iOS test is wrong because it uses the user agent (also detects Android, WinPhone 8.1 Update, etc). Something like /^iPhone|^iPad|^iPod/.test(navigator.platform) is better. Note that "iPod touch" is used for iOS 8 so don't add a $ after iPod.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works. Not the iOS check, but messageHandlers check.

Answer (score 37):

The accepted answer doesn't work as tested using the [WKWebView vs UIWebView app](http://blog.initlabs.com/post/100113463211/wkwebview-vs-uiwebview)

As the article mentions, the only HTML5 feature difference is IndexedDB support. So I'd go for a more reliable pattern with:

```
    if (navigator.platform.substr(0,2) === 'iP'){
      //iOS (iPhone, iPod or iPad)
      var lte9 = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement);
      var nav = window.navigator, ua = nav.userAgent, idb = !!window.indexedDB;
      if (ua.indexOf('Safari') !== -1 && ua.indexOf('Version') !== -1 && !nav.standalone){      
        //Safari (WKWebView/Nitro since 6+)
      } else if ((!idb && lte9) || !window.statusbar.visible) {
        //UIWebView
      } else if ((window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers) || !lte9 || idb){
        //WKWebView
      }
    }
```

You may ask: Why not using the UserAgent? That's because Android browsers use it as settings! So, we should never trust any UAs. Only browser features and property checks as such.

Also I noticed that the `QuickTime` plugin was always loaded as part of Older Safari and other Browsers in UIWebView. But the plugin is no longer present in WKWebView. So you can use the `QuickTime` plugin presence as an extra check.

9/23/16 Edit: I adjusted the code for Safari 10 which no longer allowed the sole idb check to be reliable, as mentioned by @xmnboy. To discard Safari 10, it checks for the old webkit engine bug, which only applied until Safari 9.2; and i use a `window.statusbar.visible` fallback which appears to be a reliable indicator signal after a few comparison tests between iOS 9 and 10. (please check though)

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach no longer works. It works well on an iOS 9 device, but on iOS 10 devices the check for window.indexedDB will come up true even when you are inside the UIWebView.

Comment: @xmnboy OK not surprised. I somewhat suspected this might happen. I am going to check this out and look for an alternative.

Comment: @xmnboy I forgot that I actually had found another fallback already, left handy as a comment in my script, which seems to be still true and, a working fallback for iOS10.

Comment: Thanks for that update to your detection mechanism.  :-)

Comment: `window.statusbar.visible` didn't work for us - it was true within a  WKWebkitView on iOS10.3 in our App. Maybe because our app is fullscreen? See [wantsFullScreenLayout versus modalPresentationStyle of UIModalPresentationFullScreen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455472/ios-wantsfullscreenlayout-statusbar-visible).

Comment: @robocat FYI: window.statusbar.visible = true is correctly assumed to be WKWebView! I don't have 10.3 to test yet. It works for me as expected in the WebView app with navigation and top bar removed in 10.2.1.

Comment: @hexalys `window.statusbar.visible` didn't work for me with our App (and I don't think it was due to using 10.3 beta). FYI: I noticed [this one wierd trick](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js) used to detect Safari:  `is_safari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || window.safari`

Comment: @robocat window.safari is not guarantee on mobile so I would not rely on that small snippet. Platform is more reliable.

Comment: In my instance, the script fails because of invalid JS syntax if I write `constructor` with lowercase letters. It only works if I write it as `Constructor`.

Comment: @the4kman It doesn't matter, `i` stands for case insensitive. And the syntax isn't invalid AFAIK. So I am not at all sure what you mean. Or please  tell me what environment or browser are you seeing this in.

Comment: It happens to me on Safari for Mac and iOS as well. It may be my temp webserver's fault (biz.nf).

Comment: A nasty surprise with this detection is that Chrome for iOS renders using `WKWebView`. So if you think that "being inside a WKWebView" means "being embedded within an app" you're up for a surprise.

Comment: Sidenote: although navigator.platform.substr(0,2) === 'iP' NO LONGER true on iOS 13 if Desktop Mode is used on Mobile Safari 13 (tested on iOS 13 Beta 3 and iPadOS 13 Beta 2). However in the WKWebView the platform is set correctly (because it is always Mobile Mode?!).

Comment: @robocat They spoof platform with MacIntel to enforce Desktop Mode on iPad and iPhone, in that mode. Both `MacIntel` and `navigator.maxTouchPoints` can probably be used safely to infer iPadOS/iOS in Desktop mode. I'll make edits after I test the iPadOS which I haven't gotten to yet.

Answer (score 10):

Given the change in behavior to the UIWebView that was introduced by Apple in iOS 10, here's a new answer that combines the original response by @Justin-Michael and the follow-up favorite by @hexalys.

```
var isWKWebView = false ;
if( navigator.platform.substr(0,2) === 'iP' ) {    // iOS detected
    if( window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers ) {
        isWKWebView = true ;
    }
}
```

It turns out that Justin's answer was really the better feature detection mechanism, because it works for both iOS 9 and iOS 10.

No telling what happens when we get to iOS 11.  :-)

---

**Qualification:** this test will work if you are using the [official Cordova WKWebView plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) to build your webview app, because that plugin does initialize the `addScriptMessageHandler` method, as noted by @hexalys in the comments to this post. That mechanism is being used by Cordova to define a new *JS to native bridge* when the WKWebView plugin is present.

Search for `addScriptMessageHandler` in [that plugin repo](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine) and see the very end of [the `ios-wkwebview-exec.js` file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/blob/master/src/www/ios/ios-wkwebview-exec.js) in that repo for some implementation details (or search for the string `window.webkit.messageHandlers` in that file).

Comment: Again though webkit isn't always a defined object on all iOS views by default. So not reliable on the JS side. As stated by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32785085/1647538). "The window.webkit namespace only appears in webview with script message handlers. Make sure that you have called addScriptMessageHandler method of WKUserContentController." e.g. The test app surely doesn't set it.

Comment: @hexalys -- thanks for that added bit of knowledge. I've updated my answer to include a qualification regarding my test environment. I was only concerned about the detection of WKWebVew in a Cordova (aka Adobe PhoneGap or Intel XDK) build environment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that because the latest iOS Chrome uses WKWebView as a rendering engine, Chrome is detected as WKWebView.

```
ua.indexOf('CriOS') !== -1
```

will helps to distinguish Chrome from WKWebView in App.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, you could add this code to establish communication between javascript and objective-c:

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKUserContentController *controller = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
[controller addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"javascript_observer"];
configuration.userContentController = controller;
```

...

```
webview = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:... configuration: configuration];
```

In javascript, you could test the connection like this:

```
if ( window.webkit != undefined ){
//javascript is running in webview
}
```