# WkWebKit - javascript on loaded page finds window.webkit is undefined

Tags: javascript, ios, webkit, xcode7, wkwebview

I'm experimenting with WkWebKit talking back and forth between app and page.  I can get javaScript to execute fine using WkWebView evaluateJavascript method, but when I try to execute window.webkit.messageHandlers.myHandler.postMessage('hello world!') on the JavaScript page, I find that window.webkit is not defined.

Odd...  I'm running in a simulator of iPad with ios 8.4.  I thought this was available in original version 8, no?

I can't find anyone else posting about this, so perhaps I've done something wrong?

I've even attached my Safari Developer to the simulator's browser, and in the console I try to see what window.webkit is, and sure enough, it does not exist.

Note that I add an initial script to run when the page loads (I see this in the javascript editor - the message is logged).  And I add a script message handler as well...

**[EDIT: Adding more code details here]**
Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  NSLog(@"main view Controller viewDidLoad called...");

// if we are running on an OLD ios (pre v8) WKWebView will not exist.  So don't create it if it doesn't exist...
if (NSClassFromString(@"WKWebView")) {
    // WKWebView cannot be dragged onto storyboard, so have to create it manually here.
    // We have a "ContainerView" called _webContainer that this browser view will live inside
    // First we create a web view configuration object...
    WKWebViewConfiguration *wbConfig = [WKWebViewConfiguration alloc];
    wbConfig.mediaPlaybackAllowsAirPlay = true;
    wbConfig.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false; 
    // inject some Javascript into our page before it even loads...
    NSString *scriptSource = @"console.log('Hi from the iOS app hosting this page...'); window.hostedByWkWebView=true;";
    WKUserScript *userScript = [[WKUserScript alloc]
                                initWithSource:scriptSource
                                injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentStart
                                forMainFrameOnly:YES];

    [wbConfig.userContentController addUserScript:userScript];
    [wbConfig.userContentController addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"myHandler"]; // javascript to use this would be: window.webkit.messageHandlers.myHandler.postMessage


    // Ok, the config is created, now create the WkWebView instance, passing in this config...
    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame: [_webContainer bounds] configuration:wbConfig];
    _webView.autoresizesSubviews = true;
    _webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    _webView.navigationDelegate = self;

    // Add the web view to the container view, and tell the container to automatically resize its subviews, height and width.
    [_webContainer addSubview:_webView];
    _webContainer.autoresizesSubviews = true;
    _webContainer.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    // Set the URL for the webview and navigate there...
    NSString *fullURL = @"https://myurlgoeshere.com";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
else {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot create Web View" message:@"The web view used requires iOS 8 or higher.  Sorry." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"", nil];
    [alert show];
}

//...
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I solved it and problem was that if you set `userContentController` to a new object, that `userContentController`'s `WKScriptMessageHandler`s will not be registered correctly in Apple's internal code:

```
WKUserContentController *userContentController = [WKUserContentController new];
userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "jockey")
userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "observe")
webView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController
```

fixed by using the already instantiated `userContentController` by Apple:

```
webView.configuration.userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "jockey")
webView.configuration.userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "observe")
```

Comment: you've saved my afternoon.. wrestling w/ that one a bit.  thank you! ;)

Comment: This is the right answer and solved my issue. Any idea why we have to use the existing one and not create a new one? When we create a new one and set it, e.g. self.wkWebView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController;  - does the new one get ignored? The property is not read only.

Comment: That's the one!

Comment: Wow I found this answer after an hour of wrestling with the code. WHY though?? If there's a setter available why shouldn't we be able to use a custom one? It's a bit of a bad API design on WKWebView.

Comment: thank you -- we were totally stuck until we found this post.

Comment: The doc states that webView.configuration is a copy of the configuration. Setting something on the copy is not used. But obviously, the userContentController is still a  reference to the original one which can be changed.

Answer (score 18):

The window.webkit namespace only appears in webview with script message handlers.
Make sure that you have called [addScriptMessageHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKUserContentController_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKUserContentController/addScriptMessageHandler:name:) method of WKUserContentController.

Comment: Interesting, well, I've added more coding details above and you will find that I do indeed add a ScriptMessageHandler to the WKUserContentController...  I also add an initial script to the content controller as well, and I see that does run.

Comment: Hmmm.  While my main ViewController (whose code is above) does handle the userContentController:didReceiveScriptMessage message, it is not actually a WKScriptMessageHandler object.  So I do get a compiler warning but I was under the impression it would work still anyway...

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure why it is working now, I didn't change much!  Maybe I was up too late working on it.  Anyway, I changed the subclass of the ViewController to a WKScriptMessageHandler and it worked fine.  Well, I also tried with iPhone 5 at iOS 8.4.  But then I put the VewController back to the way it was, tried on iPad iOS 8.4 simulator, and, well, it worked fine again.  I did notice that in Safari debugging the javascript in the console, I could make the call to webkit.messageHandlers...  but it didn't show webkit is defined.  Odd, but it works.

Comment: You forget call init method of WKWebViewConfiguration.

Comment: So I did... I'm new to Objective-C, so I didn't notice that myself.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this SO because I was experiencing the same issue and this is how I solved it using a custom `CustomContentController` (subclass of `WKUserContentController`) instance.

```
let userContentController = CustomContentController()
let webViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webViewConfiguration.userContentController = userContentController
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)
```

In my case the `CustomContentController` is a subclass of `WKUserContentController` in which the `add(_ scriptMessageHandler: WKScriptMessageHandler, name: String)` method is called, but I don't believe that is significant.

I believe that the `WKUserContentController` must be instantiated and applied to a `WKWebViewConfiguration` *before* the WKWebView is initialized via `WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webViewConfiguration)`

If the WKWebView has been created and *then* you try change the `WKWebViewConfiguration` you will encounter `window.webkit` not being available in the JSContext.

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving you a 50 rep bounty for this - it saved me quite some time :)

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. And after wasting 2 hours, I found this below to work fine. But I don't know why.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    WKUserContentController *userCctrl = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
    [userCctrl addScriptMessageHandler:self name:@"jscall"];
    WKWebViewConfiguration *wbConfiger = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    wbConfiger.userContentController = userCctrl;
    CGSize size = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, size.width, size.height - 20)  configuration:wbConfiger];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    webView.UIDelegate = self;
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"if (window.webkit === undefined) { alert('未注册的 window.webkit'); } else { window.webkit.messageHandlers.jscall.postMessage({title:'标题'}); }" completionHandler:^(id obj, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"run js completion with error = %@", error);
    }];
    });
}
#pragma mark -
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WKFrameInfo *)frame completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"run js alert panel message = %@", message);
    completionHandler();
}
#pragma mark -
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController *)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage *)message {
    NSLog(@"wkwebview run javascript name = %@, body = %@", message.name, message.body);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me at the end worked enabling the javascript on the webview with

```swift
webview?.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

According apple's documentation:
[image: WKUserContentController documentation]

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkusercontentcontroller

You need to create your userContentController, and add script message handlers

```
userContentController = WKUserContentController()
userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(foo, name: "foo")
```

**BEFORE** creating the webview

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.userContentController = userContentController
let webview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
```

doing it in the **AFTER** would result in error like:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.webkit.messageHandlers.foo.postMessage')
```

Comment: Would you mind [edit]ing your answer to include the bit from Apple as text? You can format it as a block quote so it's clear that it's an excerpt from them. That will make it easier for people to read if they rely on e.g. screen readers and/or translators. It might also help with indexing of the page for people with similar questions.