# How to Differentiate Mobile Safari browser and native app wkwebview using useragent

Tags: ios, safari, user-agent, wkwebview

We are currently using the below condition determine whether the web request came from iOS or not

```
window.navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)
```

We have certain scenarios where we need to do special handling if the request comes from WebView with in the native app, is there a way to differentiate whether the request is from native app webview or mobile safari. The above condition returns true for both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if page is loaded inside WKWebView in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795476/detect-if-page-is-loaded-inside-wkwebview-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks will check that out and get back.